# Send String.Empty to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string, stored-procedures

Considering this example:

```
MyParameters.Name = "Paul";
MyParameters.Nickname = String.Empty;

ExecuteStoredProcedure(MyStoredProcedure, MyParameters);
```

When my stored procedure executes it will run something like this?

```
MyStoredProcedure 'Paul',''
```

So, my question is: `C# String.Empty` is equal to `Database ''`?

PS.: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: It is actually quite hard to "consider[ing] this example", because we can't see what `ExecuteStoredProcedure` is using internally. It might matter ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an empty string is sent as an empty string. See, the values are translated and sent as expected. For example, if you needed to send `null` then you'd set `Nickname` like this:

```
MyParameters.Nickname = null;
```

Your code is also equivalent to:

```
MyParameters.Nickname = "";
```

Comment: Whether `null` behaves the same depends entirely on what the data access tool is

Comment: @MarcGravell, I see what you're saying. So there are times when you may have to use `DbNull.Value` right? If that's the case, do you know when that is?

Comment: that is simply: whenever you want to pass a logical `null`, and your database tool (unspecified in this case) doesn't do it for you ;p In particular, this can matter to stored procedures (the scenario in the question) because optional parameters could have a default value, and *not passing the parameter* can therefore be very different to *passing it as a null*.

Answer (score 4):

`String.Empty` is semantically identical to `""` in C#, which is a zero-length non-null string (whether it is *entirely* identical is more complicated, and depends on exactly what runtime version you are using). In SQL, `''` is a zero-length non-null string. So yes, `string.Empty`, `String.Empty` and `""` are all logically equivalent to `''`.

Answer (score 0):

As above said, String.Empty is same "".

Another option, declare parameter as null or "" in stored procedure like..

```
    create procedure spname 
{  
      parameter1 int = null, parameter2 varchar(50) = null, parameter3 varchar(50) = ""   
} 

as

begin

.....

end
```

While passing parameter from c# , if you not pass , then it will automatically taken blank("") or null as you declare of right side of parameter